# Interface Exploding in Adapter Pattern

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have several classes with different interfaces and now I want to unify them. Here is an example in C++

```
class Add {
public:
    void setOperand1(int o1) { operand1 = o1 };
    void setOperand2(int o2) { operand2 = o2 };

private:
    int operand1;
    int operand2;
}

class Negate {
public:
    void setOperand(int o) { operand = o; };

private:
    int operand;
}
```

I want to unify the interfaces of the two. The adapter design pattern comes to my mind. While the drawback is that the adapter interface must be the union of the two adaptees, which may cause the interface exploding if later more operator class added in.

My question, is this a best practice to use Adapter in similar scenario? And any alternatives to make it interface exploding proof? Thank you.

Comment: A bit unclear, can you show how you would apply the Adapter pattern in this case? Would you for example create all three functions `setOperand1`, `setOperand2` and `setOperand` in it? I assume that since you are afraid of the "explosion" of functions?

Comment: No, it's not. The two interface have distinct semantics and those semantics wouldn't be preserved. Want you could think about would be other ways of composition by generalising the operation interfaces and having implementations carrying the semantics. But this is just a guess as it seems like the interfaces should be composable (as mathematical expressions).

Comment: Why "exploding"?
The purpose of "adapter" is to make YY look like XX when there is a place requesting XX.
Therefore, the required interface (XX) is fixed from the beginning.

Comment: what is the interface you want to adapt to? The adapter has two sides the class you want to wrap and the interface you implement. You only show the first but the question is about an issue with the latter.

Comment: @codeling yes, I plan to summarize the public functions from all its extensions.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I plan to summarize the public functions from all its extensions.

Comment: but then its what you plan to do that causes the explosion not how you do it. If you want to adapt some classes to an interfaces that has the union of all functions of all the classes then it isnt the Adapter patterns fault that the resulting interface will have many functions